# How to use strimzi kafka bridge with confluent client to send and receive messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, strimzi

I have bridge service up and running in my k8s cluster, so i have created mapping with ambassador, so my bridge url is https://dev.ts.in. So wanna create topic, send messages with bridge url. URL works fine with curl commands, so what is the approach ? Using url with bootstrap servers wont work.Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: The bridge makes Kafka accessible with HTTP protocol. The `curl` examples should give you an idea how to use it. But you really have to implement it in whatever HTTP client you want to use and write your code. The HTTP client is not Kafka client so it does not care about any bootstrap servers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Confluent client"?